# Couchbase: NOT_STORED error during document update

Tags: java, couchbase

We're running Couchbase Server CE 5.0.1 cluster and communicate with it using [**java-client**](http://%20https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-java-client)  in version **2.7.2** to store JSON documents.

We perform document updates using [sub-document API](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/5.0/developer-guide/sub-doc-api.html) e.g.:

```
final AsyncMutateInBuilder asyncMutateInBuilder = asyncBucket.mutateIn(createDocumentId(profileId)).upsertDocument(true);
final SubdocOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder = SubdocOptionsBuilder.builder().createPath(true);
asyncMutateInBuilder.upsert(path, value, optionsBuilder)

asyncMutateInBuilder.execute()
```

During these updates frequently we're receiving **CouchbaseException** with cryptic message: `NOT_STORED`. Example stacktrace:

```
"error":"com.couchbase.client.core.CouchbaseException",
"stacktrace":"com.couchbase.client.core.CouchbaseException: NOT_STORED at 
 com.couchbase.client.java.subdoc.SubdocHelper.commonSubdocErrors(SubdocHelper.java:101) at
 com.couchbase.client.java.subdoc.AsyncMutateInBuilder$2$1.call(AsyncMutateInBuilder.java:1330) at 
 com.couchbase.client.java.subdoc.AsyncMutateInBuilder$2$1.call(AsyncMutateInBuilder.java:1276) at
 rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:69) at
 rx.observers.Subscribers$5.onNext(Subscribers.java:235) at
 rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:101) at
 rx.internal.producers.SingleProducer.request(SingleProducer.java:65) at
 rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:211) at
 rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.setProducer(OnSubscribeMap.java:102) at
 rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205) at
 rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205) at
 rx.subjects.AsyncSubject.onCompleted(AsyncSubject.java:103) at
 com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractGenericHandler.completeResponse(AbstractGenericHandler.java:508) at
 com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractGenericHandler.access$000(AbstractGenericHandler.java:86) at
 com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractGenericHandler$2.call(AbstractGenericHandler.java:540) at
 com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction$1.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:56)
...
```

Is anyone facing similar problem or know what can be the root cause? I was looking in documentation and server logs for any information about root cause of such exception but failed - in server logs I don't see any corresponding logs and documentation doesn't provide any explanation/troubleshooting in such cases.

Thanks for any suggestions or explanations!

Answer (score 1):

The "NOT_STORED" is returned by the server.  Since you say "frequently" and not consistently, and you mention 5.0.1 which is pretty ancient by now, I suspect it's related to some kind of defect in the older release.